# As3 Calculate rotationX and rotationY value

Tags: actionscript-3

I wonder if there is a formula that i can calculate the rotationX and rotationY value out of a sprite display object.

For example the sprite below. If a user set up all the points and draw out this shape. Is there a way i can find out rotationX and rotationY which can archive the same result?

I would like user to defined the container and whatever sprite drag into this container get auto rotationX and rotationY so the perspective stay the same.

[image]

Comment: I do not clearly understand what you would like to accomplish, but do you properly want to get the perceptive transformation of the shape above and apply it to the user defined sprite, so that this one fits in? -- (I cannot see any rotation going on here)

Comment: @philipp thanks mate, i want to allow the user to set up a region and apply rotationX or rotationY according tot his region, obviously this region is not just rectangle. It have skewed (rotationY)

Comment: hmm… to be honest your comment even confused me more. I suppose that the Polygon above should be a transformed (translated, rotated, skewed and scaled) Rectangle and you would like to calculate this actual applied transformation, which made it look like this?

Comment: @philipp the above Polygon have no transform, just purely draw. i want to work out if use transformed (roationY) what the value will be achieve the same result.

Comment: I don't get it, can you post an image that shows what you would like to do? Which role does rotation(Y or X) play?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if the user instead of specifying 4 points adjusted rotation(s) and amount of perspective with some sliders? Allowing the user to arbitrarily place 4 points could result in a case which doesn't have a "solution".

Comment: @Strille Thanks for that looks like i have to go for that path then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by reading through the following link:
http://zehfernando.com/2010/the-best-drawplane-distortimage-method-ever/